# How to add contact to an ongoing MMS message?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, messaging, mms

How do you add a contact to an already ongoing MMS text message

I'm using Windows  10 Mobile. I can't find any info on how to do this, not sure if it is even possible on Windows phones.

Comment: I assume you mean that you want to add participants to an existing group chat?